# How to tell TCL and TK that default `.tcl` language files should be searched locally?

Tags: c++, c, boost, tcl, tk-toolkit

When you compile TCL/Tk [manually from sources](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html) or just [install it from ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl) you get the following structure in your TCL/Tk installation folder:

```
  +- bin
       +- tcl85.dll
       +- tk85.dll
  //...
  +- lib/
       +- tcl8.5/
            //All TCL files (.tcl)
       +- tk8.5/
            //All TK files (.tcl)
  //...
```

So when you compile some app of yours and link it to TCL and TK DLL's that DLL's search for all TCL/TK files in relative to tham (to DLL's) directory ../lib/tk8.5 and ../lib/tcl8.5. This makes it quite hard to distribute your app not having to make end users install TCL and TK.

I want to distribute my C++ app.

I use [CPPTK](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/) for default GUI layout.

I want to make it possible so that end users would not have need in installing TCL and TK.  I want to provide them with folders with TK and TCL `.TCL` source files that would be located in some directory relative to my app like `extras/TCL` and `extras/TK`. How to tell TK and TCL DLLs where that source file folders are? what are TK and TCL API function names for doing that? Are there any special cpptk functions for that?

***Update***
So I tried [Donal Fellows answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553232/how-to-tell-tcl-and-tk-that-default-tcl-language-files-should-be-searched-loca/6553553#6553553) with next folder structure.

```
app/
  +- app.exe
  +- tcl85.dll
  +- tk85.dll
  +- extras/
       +- tcl/
            //All TCL files you can find in TCL install folder/ lib/tcl8.5
       +- tk/
            //All TK files you can find in TCL install folder/ lib/tk8.5
```

My code looked like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cpptk/cpptk.h"
using namespace Tk;
int main(int, char *argv[])
{
static char* str = "set extrasDir [file dirname [info nameofexecutable]]/extras\n"
"# Now use it to load some code...\n"
"source $extrasDir/tcl/init.tcl\n"
"# Another way to load code, using all *.tk files from a directory:\n"
"foreach tkFile [glob -nocomplain -directory $extrasDir/tk *.tk] {\n"
"    source $tkFile\n"
"}\n";
// This next part is in a function or method...
//std::string script("the script to evaluate goes here");
std::string result = Tk::details::Expr(str,true); // I think this is correct
std::cout<< result << std::endl;
std::cin.get();
Tk::init(argv[0]);
button(".b") -text("Say Hello");
pack(".b") -padx(20) -pady(6);
Tk::runEventLoop();
std::cin.get();
}
```

It compiles but failes on line 36 of cpptkbase.cc

BTW: I used [this html\js app to get char string.](http://jsfiddle.net/t9sgA/10/show/)

Comment: Why is this question tagged `c`?

Comment: Tcl and TK have C apis we use in c++

Comment: But your question is about C++.

Comment: The `TCL_LOCAL_MAIN_HOOK` only really makes sense on Windows (it only exists on Unix for reasons of symmetry) and then only because it lets you poke around in `main()` _after_ the de-gunking of the command line into real words (i.e., a problem that Unix platforms don't have). But I don't know why you'd actually _practically_ want to intercept at that point; it's not for non-experts IMO (and I've never ever needed it).

Comment: @Kiss: Don't add a second question into your first.

Comment: @Kiss: Ask one question per question. If you can't sort out in your mind where one Q ends and another starts, is it reasonable to expect that everyone else will do so for you?

Comment: @all - this is one question - simple - how to tall tcl\tk dlls where are main\default language files. So to be capable of redistributing your app. BTW TCL\TK structure is same other platforms - Mac OS and Linux (when you compile manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a directory that contains your binary, and you want to locate those Tcl files relative to it, like this:

```
yourapp1.0/
  +- yourapp.exe
  +- extras/
       +- tcl/
            +- foo.tcl
            +- bar.tcl
       +- tk/
            +- grill.tk
```

Then you can write Tcl code to find those scripts. That code would be like this:

```tcl
set extrasDir [file dirname [info nameofexecutable]]/extras
# Now use it to load some code...
source $extrasDir/tcl/foo.tcl
source $extrasDir/tcl/bar.tcl
# Another way to load code, using all *.tk files from a directory:
foreach tkFile [glob -nocomplain -directory $extrasDir/tk *.tk] {
    source $tkFile
}
```

If you're using a script as your main program, but otherwise set up in the structure as above, you'd use `$argv0` (a special global variable) instead of `[info nameofexecutable]`. Or possibly `[info script]` (though there are some caveats with that).

---

[EDIT]: To make that code work with C++/Tk, you need to be trickier. In particular, you need to access some extra guts:

```c++
#include "cpptk.h" // might need "base/cpptkbase.h" instead
#include <string>

// This next part is in a function or method...
std::string script("the script to evaluate goes here");
std::string result = Tk::details::Expr(script,true); // I think this is correct
```

I should warn that I don't write C++ very often so there's a fair chance that this won't work; it's just based off reading the C++/Tk source and taking a guess. *Caveat emptor*.

Comment: Note that `glob` returns the list of files in unspecified order (actually the order that the OS lists them in, which depends on all sorts of factors) so use `lsort` on that list of files if you want to read them in predictable order.

Comment: And “tell Tcl where files are” is done by using full pathnames. There _is_ a concept of packages which can be stored in groups, but they're a higher-level idea.

Comment: I found out that actually all you need to do in order to acomplish what I asked for was to set up some enviroment variables [TCL_LIBRARY](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1629) and [TK_LIBRARY](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3762). Thay can be set to relative to your app values.